# How to binding multiple properties using an object in Angular?

Tags: angular

In Vue

```js
<Person v-bind='{name: "Tom", color: "Blue"}'></Person>
```

In React

```
<Person {...{name: "Tom", color: "Blue"}}></Person>
```

In Angular?

**UPDATE**

The Person component has 2 input properties. How to quickly bind an object to this component?

Data is `const it = {name: "Tom", color: "Blue"}`

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './person.component.html'
})
export class PersonComponent {
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() color: string;
}
```

```html
<Person ???="it" />
```

Comment: you mean directly do it on the HTML?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't know how to describe it. I hope to get results like this`<Person name="Tom" color="Blue">`. Or there are other best practices in Angular.

Comment: You need to provide to us some more information, like what is `Person` ? Is it a component? And if yes, what is the input?

Assuming the above is correct and you have a listPersons input, you probably going to have something like

`<Person [listPerson]="You Object in here"></Person>`

Comment: Check the link from @KNeerajLal, that documentation along with my example is likely what you want, assuming we understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

your Person component

```
  name: string;
  color: string;
  @Input('personData') set _person({ name, color }: { name: string; color: string }) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
  }
```

You main.component

```
 <app-person [personData]="{name: 'Tom', color: 'Blue'}"></app-person>
```

NOTE: (you can chose use `Input('your input') whatever(..)` or `@Input()yourInput(..){}`

Comment: If this component is defined in a UI library and I cannot modify the input, what should I do?

Comment: You can pass as Input also an object (see that, in this case you only have an object that it's shared between the parent and the child (any change in parent or in child change the object). The component should be an `Input` or a `method` to change this properties

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the interface to handle this

*Person-detial component*

```
@Component({
      selector: 'person-detail',
      template: `
      <div>Name : {{person.name}} </div>
      <div>Color : {{person.color}}</div>
      `,
    })
    export class PersonComponent {
      @Input() person: Person;
    }
```

*Person interface*

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}
```

you can call the component like it

```
<person-detail
  [person]="{ name: 'Testing User', color: 'black' }"
></person-detail>
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind the name and color inputs to the Person component, you can use the following code:

**parent-component.html**

<Person [name]="'John Doe'" [color]="'blue'"/>